# Como ler o valor de um campo readonly?

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Estou tentando ler o valor de um campo readonly, mas não estou conseguindo acessar o value dele, não tem o valor no html só aparece na browser.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1">
    <p>Numero 1</p>
    <input type="text" name="numero1" id="numero1" readonly="">
    <p>Numero 2</p>
    <input type="text" name="numero2" id="numero2" readonly="">
    <div><p>a soma dos numeros é</p>
    <input type="text" name="soma" id="soma">
    <p>a subtração dos numeros é</p>
    <input type="text" name="subtraca" id="subtracao">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Realizar Operacao" id="Operacao" name="Operacao" onclick="startOperacao()">

    <h3>Resultado</h3>
    <div id="divResult" name="divResult">

    </div>
    <div style="width:500px;visibility: hidden;" id="divNext">
                    <p style="text-align:right;">
                        <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Próxima Tarefa" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="nextStep();">
                    </p>
    </div>              
    </form>
```

Já tentei usar o;

```
 var numero1 = doc.GetElementById("numero1");
```

e o `InnerHtml` vem nulo.

Estou usando `webBrowser`.

Tem alguma forma de ler o valor ?

Preenchimento do campo.

```
<script>
function start()
{
document.form1.numero1.value = parseInt(Math.random()*10000);
document.form1.numero2.value = parseInt(Math.random()*10000);
}
function startOperacao()
{
var numero1 = parseInt(document.form1.numero1.value);
var numero2 = parseInt(document.form1.numero2.value);

var somaEntrada = parseInt(document.form1.soma.value);
var subtracaoEntrada = parseInt(document.form1.subtracao.value);

var soma = numero1 + numero2;
var subtracao = numero1 - numero2;

var textoResposta='';
if(soma==somaEntrada && subtracao==subtracaoEntrada)
{
    textoResposta= 'O Primeiro numero é: ' + numero1 + '\nO Segundo numero é:' + numero2 + '\nA soma é:' + soma + '\nA Subtração é ' + subtracao + '\nOs resultados que você colocou estão corretos';
    document.getElementById('divNext').style='width:500px;visibility: display';
}
else{
    textoResposta = 'O resultado não está certo. você deve fazer a Soma e a Subtração e colocar nos lugares corretos';
    document.getElementById('divNext').style='width:500px;visibility: hidden';
}
document.getElementById('divResult').innerText = textoResposta;

}
function nextStep()
{
    setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = "entrada.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.php)
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Só por garantia poderia postar como é realizado o preenchimento do campo, na função: startOperacao()

Comment: @CaiqueRomero editado.

Comment: remove o parseInt e realiza um teste

Comment: @CaiqueRomero, esse site não é meu, e não tenho acesso a ele, estou usando o webBrowseer com windows forms C#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091938/get-value-from-read-only-input-with-c-sharp-web-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma pergunta similar no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091944/how-to-get-html-textbox-value)  veja se te atende:

```
dynamic elePrice = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("price").DomElement;
string sValue = elePrice.value;
```

Ou se você não puder usar `dynamic` tente

```
mshtml.IHTMLInputElement elePrice =(mshtml.IHTMLInputElement)webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("price").DomElement;
string sValue = elePrice.value;
```